# Need a correct way to export typescript class from my package, so that it can be extended by other package

Tags: typescript

I’m working on a typescript library package (say ‘MyPkg’) that has some classes (say ‘MyPkgClass’ located in some sub-directory [eg: src/path/to/mypkg] ) with some required functionality,
The consumer package, say ‘OtherPkg’ is expected to extend ‘MyPkgClass’ and then define any additional functionality

The idea behind this is to provide some basic features (under my control) to the consuming pakages, and those I may need to tweak later on, enhance etc.

Testing this locally, with npm link  in OtherPkg under I realise that I need to import ‘MyPkgClass’ as

```
Import MyPkgClass from “MyPkg/bin/<path>/<to>/MyPkgClass”
```

obviously, this is bad as it would restrict me from moving the file / renaming the class if I feel the need to re-organize at a later point of time.
I could of-course have a different class place at a fixed location under ‘bin’ and extend that from ‘MyPkgClass’, so that the consumer OtherPkg doesn’t break. But this feels like a bad design, probably not the right / recommended way.

What is the correct way to expose MyPkgClass? Should I be re-exporting it from Index.ts of MyPkg?
Should I be exporting MyPkgClass as a Type?

Could anyone help with standard typescript documentation, or some examples?
— a noob  looking for help

I've tried to search typecript documentation for the above usecase, but I'm not getting the right hits, probably not using the right search terms even :(

Comment: I suspect re-export is what I need, will check it out. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the problem of needing to import like

`Import MyPkgClass from “MyPkg/bin/<path>/<to>/MyPkgClass”`

You can export it from index.ts at the root of your sub-project `MyPkg` like below:

```
MyPkg/index.ts

export * from './bin/<path>/<to>/MyPkgClass”';
```

and then in the other module where you want to use it.

```
import MyPkgClass from 'MyPkg';
```

Refer https://balramchavan.medium.com/smarter-way-to-organize-import-statements-using-index-ts-file-s-in-angular-c685e9d645b7

For extending the base class you can simply do:

```
class OtherPkgClass extends MyPkgClass {
  constructor(someParameter: String) {
    super(someParameter);
  }

  private newMethod() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Refer https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#inheritance